# Python sounddevice module outputs Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, audio, module

Need help

What i want :

I want to record microphone and get the duration from a txt file

Code:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import soundfile as sf
fs=44100
dur = open("duration.txt", "r")
duration = dur.read()
print (duration)
myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2,dtype='float64')
print ("Recording Audio")
sd.wait()
sf.write('myfile.wav', myrecording, fs, subtype='PCM_24')
```

duration.txt contains just a 7

Output:

```
7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio.py", line 9, in <module>
    myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2,dtype='float64')
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\portfowardtesting\python\lib\site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 271, in rec
    ctx.frames = ctx.check_out(out, frames, channels, dtype, mapping)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\portfowardtesting\python\lib\site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 2437, in check_out
    out = np.empty((frames, channels), dtype, order='C')
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to do `print(duration * fs)`, this might give you a hint.

The problem is that the `duration` you read from the file is a string, you should first convert it to a number.

In other words:

```
duration = int(dur.read())
```